# How to store large list items to get maximum speed and efficiency

Tags: android, list, listview, data-structures

I am creating an app in Android and I have a large number of string data, lets way 10,000 or more words (items), I want to display it in a list view. My question is where should I put my (source) data

1. String Array in Xml file
2. In DB (then i have to place an external DB)
3. Reading data from a simple text file, CSV etc

Here my only concern is speed, which way is faster and why.

Note: I am currently placing data in Xml as string array and getting it in Array in activity, but it is slow it takes few sec/moments to load data from xml but only for the first time.

Comment: what about, testing it yourself?

Comment: try using it with Json format. Android has Json support.

Comment: My guess is item 2 (DB) with lazy load (you can load 100 items and before user scroll to end of list, you can get more 100 and call notifyDataSetChanged from adapter. But, if your word list is always static, a JSON file can be a more efficient choice, like @MuratNafiz says.

Comment: @dougcunha thanks I will try Json, I think it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the code to parse/load content form json/db in a AsyncTask for more speed. I load 5000 rows with ~ 400 chars per row. It takes without AsyncTask much longer.

```
    private class YourTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... s) {

            //Here you have to make the loading / parsing tasks
            //Don't call any UI actions here. For example a Toast.show() this will couse Exceptions
            // UI stuff you have to make in onPostExecute method

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // This method will called during doInBackground is in process
            // Here you can for example show a ProgressDialog
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
            // onPostExecute is called when doInBackground finished
            // Here you can for example fill your Listview with the content loaded in doInBackground method

        }

}
```

To execute you just have to call:

```
new YourTask().execute("");
```

Here you can learn more about AsyncTasks:

[AsyncTask developer Guide](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDQQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html&ei=XXWvUJivB8XIswajxIDABg&usg=AFQjCNE8gLVXz1Hwq4rI8oxRkZNHjhRzpQ&sig2=CmICU1zanbO_qVgO4V9uEg)